# missing unix socket on Cloud Run deploy when using MySQL

Tags: google-cloud-run

I am having a weird issue with Cloud Run in Zurich region.

I have deployed my app from Cloud Build as:

```
   "--region",
     "europe-west6",
   "--platform",
        "managed",
   "--allow-unauthenticated",
   "--add-cloudsql-instances",
        "$PROJECT_ID:europe-west6:mysql",
```

I see the YAML and in the interface correctly set.

I expected the `/cloudsql/project:europe-west6:mysql` unix socket path be there and be created, but actually the folder is empty.

When I list the files from root directory `/` I see the `cloudsql` folder getting setup

```
Array
(
    [0] => .
    [1] => ..
    [2] => bin
    [3] => boot
    [4] => cloudsql
    [5] => dev
    [6] => etc
    [7] => home
    [8] => lib
    [9] => lib64
    [10] => media
    [11] => mnt
    [12] => opt
    [13] => proc
    [14] => root
    [15] => run
    [16] => sbin
    [17] => srv
    [18] => sys
    [19] => tmp
    [20] => usr
    [21] => var
)
```

but after I list the files from `/cloudsql` the folder is empty.

```
Array
(
    [0] => .
    [1] => ..
)
```

`Current script owner: root` I printed this as well.

So apparently I don't understand why the folder gets created but the unix socket is not built by Cloud Run. I tried to use the interface to delete the SQL connection, then the `/cloudsql` folder is disappearing, and if I put it back from the `UI` or either `gcloud run deploy` the `/cloudsql` folder is visible, but no files under it.

I am under user root, permissions should be all set. What could be wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The series of bugs are on our end, the **Cloud Run service runs fine**.

1.
A couple of issues that could led to this problem:

- public IP must be set on Cloud SQL
- the container MySQL client shall support the MySQL version. We had issues that MySQL 8 wasn't supported.
  The reported error was: `Server sent charset (255) unknown to the client.`

2. 

Now on the socket file. Which is not a regular file.
Some programming languages and some library implementations check for the existence of this file.
They could check with wrong function!!! For example in PHP, `scandir` doesn't list the socket files only regular directories and files. This was not aware to me until today, and let to the wrong report earlier.
Also in PHP `is_file` returns false for `socket` type files. The proper way to check is `file_exists`.

3.
On top of this, Linux distributions, may not list socket files, which I've tried doing like:

```
$ find / -type s
Array
(
    [0] => /dev/log
)
```

as you see didn't listed anything with `/cloudsql/*` the same if I had run `lsof -i`
I don't have a clue why /cloudsql files are not listed. Maybe you can explain this.

4.
When you get: `(HY000/2002): No such file or directory`
it could be that your default MySQL client setup for example in PHP it has `/tmp/mysql.sock` in php.ini and it's reading from there.

Double check is needed how to override the `unix_socket` connection string.
Common errors are that people use `unix_socket:/cloudsql/socket` with double colon <- which is wrong

accepted way to define connection string is with `unix_socket=/cloudsql/socket`

5. there could be potentially another reason that your script runs so early that the `/cloudsql` path is not correctly setup. I could not test this.